# Unzipping a file in Google Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I am using Data flow templates [API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-utilities#bulk-decompress-cloud-storage-files) to decompress a zipped file I have in Google Storage Bucket. This zip file in turn has multiple folders and files. Now the Data flow api decompresses my zip file but writes the output into a plain text file. What I want is only unzipping of my input file and extract all contents within. How can I do this?

My zip contains following heirarchy

```
file.zip
|
|_folder1
| |
| |_file1
| |_file2
| |_file3
|_file
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline print only the file in failure in a plain text file. You can see the detail of the process [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/a0ed6003f4e713785e42e114720fe92942f582f0/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/BulkDecompressor.java#L221-L253)

Are you sure that your files are readable and well decompressed?

Comment: Hi @guillaume blaquiere, Yes the content of the zip file is readable. The zip has structure that I have updated in question. It has files and folders in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compress and decompress files using Data flow from console.

> On the settings it says:  Bulk Decompress Cloud Storage Files template
>   Required Parameters. The input filepattern to read from (e.g.,
>   gs://bucket-name/uncompressed/*.gz).

So the compressing/decompressing works at the level of files, by matching the pattern. I do not know how did you compressed or decompressed at the level of folders. When I try to input a folder name for the input parameter I get: "No files matched spec Error."

Comment: Hi @marian.vladoi, I already have a zip file uploaded to bucket. I have to unzip the contents of this zip to a location in the bucket. This zip was not created via this API but locally created and uploaded. The structure of this zip file I have updated in question above

I want a similar hierarchy when extracted via the API. But I am getting a plain text file with binary data.

Comment: The compression algorithm must be one of : GZIP, BZIP2, DEFLATE

Comment: I checked the java code and I can see only this steps:  
      1) Find all files matching the input pattern
      2) Decompress the files found and output them to the output directory
      3) Write any errors to the failure output file
    There if nothing recursively applied to folders of folders of files. So I think the Api only decompress files and not folder.

Comment: After I tried to decompress a folder I got the same output file as you . That is the failure output file and not the result of the pipeline

Comment: I am also trying to send a compressed file with a directory structure and would like the same directory structure expanded on Cloud Storage.
That would be helpful as I am trying to create many small files on Google Storage and `gsutil cp` is slow in that case.